# Download and open png image?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, this script loads on the start of the program. I want to download an image, and after that show it on the main screen. What should I do? The following code did not work.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;  

public class PushNotifications : MonoBehaviour {

    IEnumerator Start () {
        Texture2D textWebPic = null;
        WWW image = new WWW("http://www.test.com/image.png");        
        yield return image;
        image.LoadImageIntoTexture(textWebPic);
    }

void Update () {

    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you checked image.error property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass null to `LoadImageIntoTexture`, since then Unity has no idea where to put the output (it is not ref). The texture must be initialized first.

It does not really matter, however, with what size or format you initialize it, unity will resize it anyway. So you can initialize some dummy, like this to load the image:

```
IEnumerator Start () {
        Texture2D textWebPic = new Texture2D(2,2);
        WWW image = new WWW("http://www.test.com/image.png");        
        yield return image;
        image.LoadImageIntoTexture(textWebPic);
    }
```

Another, and probably better option is to use `WWW.texture` instead of LoadImageIntoTexture, like this:

```
IEnumerator Start () {
        WWW image = new WWW("http://www.test.com/image.png");        
        yield return image;
        Texture2D textWebPic = image.texture;
    }
```

See WWW class reference for more examples:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

And then to show it on the screen you have multiple option - creating a material with this texture, creating sprite from texture (best for 2d games) or simply use `Graphics.DrawTexture`.